# How to find a .pdf or .txt or folder in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, file, dropbox

I am working in iPhone Dropbox app, Using DropboxSDK to develop this, I get the files from My Drop-box account like APP, Getting Started.pdf, Photos, Public the i have stored this files in NSMutableArray and its show in TableView, when the user select the file in TableView, then i get that items from DidSelectRow delegate. then How to find that files? please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` for this purpose.

For example:-

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array with objects];
NSPredicate *predictate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %d",@"isDefault",1];
NSArray *filterArray = [mutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predictate];
NSLog(@"filterArray :%@",filterArray);
```

OR also you can try with this :-

```
NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *item;
    NSArray *contents = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];
    for (item in contents)
    {
        if ([[item pathExtension]isEqualToString:@".pdf"])
        {
            [matches addObject:item];
        }
    }
```